# Are answers which drip feed information in subsequent comments acceptable?

Tags: discussion, answers, suggested-edits, comments

I have just had this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22993551) rejected. The new user has posted a short answer and then expanded upon it, not by editing [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658561/how-to-add-a-dynamic-link-url-url-name-inside-of-a-text-field-from-admin/56104139#56104139), but by adding multiple comments. I had attempted to consolidate the comments into the answer.

I had always thought that answers should be compact and not require the reader to have to read through all of the comments. Was I incorrect in assuming that?

Comment: Side note: I have reapplied your rejected edit.

Comment: @duplode excellent. Many thanks.

Comment: Answers should be complete, you should read the comments (you shouldn't ***have*** to, but you should; or skip them at your peril), and you can flag your review with a custom Mod message. Since your changes were extensive and the user was last [online **2** hours ago](https://stackexchange.com/users/6588034/loki-nightray?tab=activity) **I** wouldn't have risked the rejection and the additional work to flag; that doesn't mean that you were wrong, just that you pay double.

Comment: Can we get a word to those reviewers, please.

Comment: @IanKemp - it isn't particularly easy, see [Use comment reply to contact reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328103/use-comment-reply-to-contact-reviewers)

Comment: I think Ian was referring to moderators getting a word to those reviewers ;)

Comment: @Tas - indeed. They very obviously looked only at the length and ignored the content and context. The review queues exist to improve the quality of the site, and these reviewers actively did the opposite by rejecting this high-quality edit. Not to mention that such poor reviews discourage people like Greenonline who put in this much-appreciated effort to improve quality, and are thus the exact kind of people that SO wants and needs.

Comment: Your edit summary could've been made clearer by specifically mentioning these comments came from OP. I wouldn't approve such a significant suggested edit incorporating comments if those comments came from other people, but I would trivially approve it if they were OP's comments. (Of course this may not have gotten your edit approved, and reviewers should ideally compare the comments with your edit regardless, but most probably won't and the above should help with getting it approved).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your edit was entirely reasonable, as there is no obvious reason that would justify not having the information in those comments in the answer. Considering you had left a very clear edit summary, I'd say the reviewers were at fault.

Another thing you did right was leaving a comment to the OP explaining the point of your edit. In this case, additionally noting that edits are, in fact, possible was also appropriate. In such cases, writing `[edit]` in a comment will create a link that the OP can use to edit the post.

Comment: As an aside, way the edit comment is placed in the review UI (at least the version I see by following OP's link), my eyes tend to skip over it. Maybe there should be a feature request on that.

Comment: @Haem - Yes, I totally agree, it isn't particularly prominent, as the eyes tend to immediately gravitate to the edit rather than the description.

Comment: @Haem I agree, I definitely would have rejected this edit too without seeing the reason from OP

Comment: WRT the edit summary, I'd have probably said "multiple comments from the OP", as currently it could be read that other users commented on an answer to help improve it and that was added to the answer, which may "deviate from the original".

Comment: @Tas Still, I'd say the edit summary as written by the Meta OP should have been enough. The reviewers should have carried out due diligence by looking at the whole post.

Comment: Yeah I definitely agree, the edit summary as-is is still fine and the reviewers should've checked rather than _whatever went through their heads_

Comment: It appears the feature request for a more prominent edit summary has been made three  years ago [on main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275870/make-the-edit-summary-more-prominent-in-the-suggested-edit-review-queue)